# Highest ancestor in a TreeView as commandparameter

Tags: wpf, events, parameters, treeview, double-click

I have a hierarchical treeview in WPF. I use http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/ for eventbinding with the viewmodel.

When I doubleclick an item in the treeview, I always want to pass the root type as the commandparameter.

Example:
A
..B
....C
D
..E

When I click on 'A', 'B' or 'C' I want 'A' as commandparameter.
When I click on 'D' or 'E' I want 'D' as commandparameter.

This is what I have so far, this always sends the item clicked as commandparameter:

```
    <Setter Property="acb:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="MouseDoubleClick"/>
    <Setter Property="acb:CommandBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SomeCommand}"/>
    <Setter Property="acb:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
```

I suppose I have to do binding with RelativeSource, I can't figure it out..

Regards,

Michel

Comment: If you know how many levels each item is nested you may be able to use "Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=DataContext.AProperty}" where you need to set the AncestorLevel correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot create a binding which is equivalent to the wanted expression, you might be better off passing the current item as parameter and finding the root node in the command code.